# Cannot upload wav file on an Azure blob container using PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to upload audio files in wav format to an Azure container using the Azure SDK for PHP but the content of the wav does not upload. Indeed, I only have a 0 bytes .wav file in my container so i'm not able to use it.

I have tested several codes but this is the best one I have. I am not an expert in PHP but I force him to use this language to integrate it into a CRM.

When I load a text file it also uploads empty so the problem doesn't come from the way I read the file.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
    <?php

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\ListBlobsOptions;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;

    $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=".getenv('ACCOUNT_NAME').";AccountKey=".getenv('ACCOUNT_KEY');

    // Create blob client.
    $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);

    $fileToUpload = "audio.wav";

    if (!isset($_GET["Cleanup"])) {

          $containerName = "cs-blob-input";

        try {

            // Getting local file so that we can upload it to Azure
            $myfile = fopen($fileToUpload, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fclose($myfile);

            # Upload file as a block blob
            echo "Uploading BlockBlob: ".PHP_EOL;


            $content = fopen($fileToUpload, "r");

            //Upload blob
            $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $fileToUpload, $content);

            // List blobs.
            $listBlobsOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
            echo "These are the blobs present in the container: ".PHP_EOL;

            do{
                $result = $blobClient->listBlobs($containerName, $listBlobsOptions);
                foreach ($result->getBlobs() as $blob)
                {
                    echo $blob->getName().PHP_EOL;
                }

                $listBlobsOptions->setContinuationToken($result->getContinuationToken());
            } while($result->getContinuationToken());

        }
        catch(ServiceException $e){
            $code = $e->getCode();
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
            echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
        }
        catch(InvalidArgumentTypeException $e){
            // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
            // Error codes and messages are here:
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
            $code = $e->getCode();
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
            echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
        }
    }
    else
    {

        try{
            // Delete container.
            echo "Deleting Container".PHP_EOL;
            echo $_GET["containerName"].PHP_EOL;
            echo "<br />";
            $blobClient->deleteContainer($_GET["containerName"]);
        }
        catch(ServiceException $e){
            $code = $e->getCode();
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
            echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
// Getting local file so that we can upload it to Azure
$myfile = fopen($fileToUpload, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fclose($myfile);
```

What is happening is, you open a file "audio.wav" for **writing**.
Based on [official docs (See the *mode* parameter 'w')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters) your file will be created if it not exists. Then, if it exists, it will be truncated to zero size. Then you close the file.

After that you do:

```
$content = fopen($fileToUpload, "r");
```

Which reads an **empty** file. So the uploaded content is => 0 in size

Comment: Hi Anton, thank your for your answer.

When I open the file for Reading instead of Writing, i can upload the content of a text file but not an audio. Do you know if fopen works to open a wav file ?

Comment: @MatthieuRousseau you need to open a file in a binary read mode `fopen($fileToUpload, "rb")` -> the mode is set to **rb** . Keep in mind that fopen just opens the file and return a handler to you, so after that you need to do something like **fread** . See the second example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)